# How to set ENV variables from at /etc/profile?

Tags: java

My question is like below;

1. This is the code.

   ```
   [root@localhost eclipse]# java -version

   java version "1.6.0_17"
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.7.4) (rhel-1.21.b17.el6-i386)
   OpenJDK Client VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)

   [root@localhost eclipse]# vim /etc/profile

   [root@localhost eclipse]# source /etc/profile

   [root@localhost eclipse]# java -version

   java version "1.6.0_17"
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.7.4) (rhel-1.21.b17.el6-i386)
   OpenJDK Client VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)

   [root@localhost eclipse]# ./eclipse
   ```
2. This is what i added at /etc/profile like below;

   ```
   JAVA_HOME=/root/jdk1.8.0_91

   PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

   export JAVA_HOME PATH
   ```
3. This is error message

   ```
   Version 1.6.0_17 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. 

   Version: 1.8 or greater is required.
   ```
4. How to change the JAVA version?

Comment: please indent the code first.

Comment: Take a loook to [https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your system already knows where a java executable version is, and you've told it another place to look (with your `PATH` change), but you've added that at the END Of the list of places to look.  It will never look there because it's already found a java executable, and it stops looking once it's find one.

The **simplest** (and I believe wrong) way to do it would be to change the path command to:

```
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

And leave the rest as is.

This will tell your system to look in that java folder first, **BUT** it will look there **for every application** (and not find it, then look in the next folder), which is why it's wrong - it will slow stuff down on your computer.

To do it the right way will take a bit of detective work.

start with

```
which java
```

This will tell you which java executable it's using (the 1.6.0 one). On my machine it's

```
/usr/bin/java
```

ok, so put that into an `ls -l` command - but remember to substitute the path that you got above:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/java
```

On my machine it says:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jul  2 11:39 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
```

The arrow here is important (and the `l` right at the start). That means that `/usr/bin/java` is a symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/java`

So do the `ls -l` trick again with that, and repeat until you get something that's NOT a symbolic link - that is something without the arrow.

```
greg@greg-mint ~ $ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Jul  2 11:39 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
greg@greg-mint ~ $ ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6464 Jul 28 14:31 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

In my case the `/etc/alternatives/java` is the last one that's a symbolic link. The one with `openjdk-amd64` doesn't have the arrow so it's a "real" file, not a symbolic link.  Also in my case, I'm already pointing at a 1.8 version executable.  Yours should currently be pointing at the 1.6 version executable, which we'll need to change.

What you need to do is identify the LAST symbolic link, and then tweak that.

In my case the last symbolic link is `/etc/alternatives/java`.

So you need to replace your last symbolic link with one that links to the java in `/root/jdk1.8.0_91`   (which, by the way, is an *extremely* unusual place to put it).

You do this with the `ln` command:
    ln -s file1 link1

Where `file1` is the java executable you *want* to use, and `link1` is that last symbolic link you found (more detail on `ln`: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-soft-link-or-symbolic-link/).

So on *my* machine, and you'll have to adjust this one too, for yours, I'd do something like:

```
sudo ln -s /root/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java /etc/alternatives/java
```

So now your system wide default java will point to the one you want.

You then take out the `PATH` modification to your profile (and from the export statement) but leave the `JAVA_HOME` one there.

And you should be good to go.